# Cohomology of the ring of integers of a local or global field

Tags: group-cohomology, galois-cohomology

Let $\mathcal{O}$ denote the ring of integers in the separable closure $K^{sep}$ of a local or global field $K$ with absolute Galois group $G_K$. What is known about the cohomology groups $H^i(G_K,\mathcal{O})$ ?

The results related to this issue that I'm aware of are :

1. If $K$ is local, $L/K$ is tamely ramified if and only if $\mathcal{O}_L$ is a cohomologically trivial $\mathrm{Gal}(L/K)$-module (as I know this is a result of Noether, *Normalbasis bei Körpern ohne höhere Verzweigung*).
2. For $L/K$ a finite Galois extension of number fields with Galois group G and $i\in \mathbb{Z}$, $$\hat{H}^i(G,\mathcal{O}_L)=\bigoplus_{\mathfrak{p}}\bigoplus_{\mathfrak{P}|\mathfrak{p}}\hat{H}^i(\mathrm{Gal}(L_{\mathfrak{P}}/K_{\mathfrak{p}}),\mathcal{O}_{L_{\mathfrak{P}}})$$ (see for instance Furuta, Sawada, *On the Galois cohomology group of the ring of integers in a global field and its adele ring*) where $\hat{H}$ denote Tate cohomology. Hence by passing to the direct limit we get for all $i\geq 1$ identifications
   $$ H^i(G_K,\mathcal{O}) = \bigoplus_{\mathfrak{p}}H^i(G_{\mathfrak{p}},\mathcal{O}_{K_{\mathfrak{p}}^{sep}})$$ and the global problem reduces to the local one.
3. A p-adic local field is of strict cohomological dimension $2$ (for a local field of characteristic $p$ it is $\leq 3$), so $H^i(G_K,\mathcal{O})=0$ for $i\geq 3$ in the p-adic case (for $i\geq 3$ in the char $p$ case)
4. For $K$ local, we cannot expect that $H^1(G_L,\mathcal{O})=H^2(G_L,\mathcal{O})=0$ for every finite Galois extension $L/K$. Indeed this implies that $\mathcal{O}$ is cohomologically trivial, hence that $\mathcal{O}_L$ is a cohomologically trivial $\mathrm{Gal}(L/K)$-module for every finite Galois extension $L/K$. This is false by 1. (one can observe for instance that $\hat{H}^0(\mathrm{Gal}(L/K),\mathcal{O}_L)=\mathcal{O}_K/\mathfrak{m}_K$ for a weakly totally ramified cyclic extension $L/K$ of local fields of degree $p$, where $p$ is the residual characteristic).